# Unable to execute "trunk serve"

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, yew, trunk-rs

I was getting into Rust and looking at these simple instructions for Yew framework (a frontend framework for Rust): https://yew.rs/docs/tutorial.

I followed the instructions up until the command

```
trunk serve --open
```

However, something somewhere fails.

**This is what I'm getting:**

```
2022-05-06T19:07:54.087214Z  INFO  starting build
2022-05-06T19:07:54.087870Z  INFO spawning asset pipelines
2022-05-06T19:07:54.168329Z  INFO building yew-app
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
2022-05-06T19:07:54.232154Z  INFO fetching cargo artifacts
2022-05-06T19:07:54.295124Z  INFO processing WASM for yew-app
2022-05-06T19:07:54.301974Z  INFO downloading wasm-bindgen version="0.2.80"
2022-05-06T19:07:54.302269Z ERROR ❌ error
error from HTML pipeline

Caused by:
    0: error from asset pipeline
    1: failed downloading release archive
    2: unsupported architecture
2022-05-06T19:07:54.302531Z  INFO  serving static assets at -> /
2022-05-06T19:07:54.302591Z  INFO  server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

**This is my Cargo.toml file:**

```ini
[package]
name = "yew-app"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
yew = "0.19"
```

**Output after I run `rustup target list --installed` command:**

```
aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

**Machine:** M1 Mac (with Apple Silicon chip)

**Rust version:** 1.60.0

**trunk version:** 0.15.0

Any help would be appreciated as I'm just getting into Rust and Web Assembly.

Comment: I can reproduce this on M1 Mac as well.

Comment: I guess this is the solution: https://github.com/thedodd/trunk/pull/375

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fix it by installing `wasm-bindgen-cli`:

`cargo install --locked wasm-bindgen-cli`

This is mentioned in this PR on *trunk's* GitHub: https://github.com/thedodd/trunk/pull/375

Comment: Correct, it compiles and serves successfully now, thank you!

Comment: @Unapiedra, does it typically take awhile to install `wasm-bindgen-cli`?

Comment: @Unapiedra, installing `wasm-bindgen-cli` did not resolve my issue of running `trunk serve`.